# How to use ESP-WROOM-32 to send wireless TX and RX commands from a PIC?

Tags: pic, pcb-design, schematics, wireless, datasheet

I want to have the possibility to send the commands of a PIC in a way that it's wireless and I thought it would be a good idea to use a ESP WROOM 32.

In the datasheet it has the following schematic:

[image]

I came up with what I think is needed for my case:

[image]

But probably would it be good to have the JTAG included in my board? That way I can program the ESP anytime.

Comment: It's unclear what you are really trying to do here but it would be best to prove the idea with a breadboard setup or similar prototype technique before you make a custom board, especially as the scheme may not work very well even with the best schematic.

Comment: Can you provice the whole shematic including the PIC? Maybe its possible to use the ESP only, since its a very powerful µC.